# Magento 1: unset a previously set query parameter or reinit the request

Tags: php, magento-1, controllers, http-request

So I've made an integration test where my `setUp()` method **add a query parameter to the request** like this:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->setQuery('entry', 'value');
```

However, the **tests that run after this test will have their request still containing the query parameter.**

The only way I managed to avoid that was by adding the following line in my `tearDown()` method :

```
unset($_GET['entry']);
```

I want to know **what is the proper Magento way of doing that ?**

I tried calling:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->setQuery('entry', null);
```

But I get the following error:

> Invalid value passed to setQuery(); must be either array of values or key/value pair

I also tried:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('entry', null);
```

No error but still does not remove the query parameter.

Even **reinit the entire request would be fine if that's possible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1 does not have a "proper Magento way" for integration tests because it does not have them.

The EcomDev_PHPUnit framework replaces `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` with an extended version which has a `reset()` method, but without such a workaround it is not possible to reset the properties of the request object.

---

The good thing about `setQuery()` is that it internally modifies the superglobal `$_GET`, which is why `unset($_GET['entry']);` works.

The same goes for `setPost()` and `$_POST`, and to revert a call to `setParam()` you can use `setParam($key, null)`.

---

Another idea is to replace the request object with a new instance in your `setUp()` or `tearDown()` methods:

```
Mage::app()->setRequest(new Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http());
```

You can also do the same with the response object:

```
$response = new Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http();
$response->headersSentThrowsException = Mage::$headersSentThrowsException;
$this->_response->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
Mage::app()->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: I tried `setQuery($key, null)` as well as `setParam($key, null)` but of them work. I also tried `Mage::app()->setRequest(new Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http());` but it didn't work either :(

Comment: setParam and setQuery do different things, that's why I said using $_GET is what you have to do in your case

Comment: yeah that's what I thought too, @vinai also suggested to use `Mage::reset()` but it seems kind of slow